in bash how do I separate the escape sequence with the actual number?
for example echo -e "\001\033[5m\033[7m\002${var}\001\033[0m\002"
If the var is starting with non number character it works.
However, if the var starting with number it fails
for example var = 5
then the string is "\001\033[5m\033[7m\0025\001\033[0m\002"` for some reason it won't blink the 5 the screen has a blank line

Don't use echo -e in the first place. Even the POSIX spec for echo recommends using printf instead, which lets you distinguish between %b for things that are supposed to be honored as escape sequences and %s for things that are supposed to be printed exactly as they are.

For completeness, the issue is when the var has an octal digit as the most significant digit - so if var were 8 or 9 (or 81...) it would work as expected.

For historical purposes, this was identified as a "bash bug" in 2011: https://superuser.com/a/301355

Described as a bug, certainly. Identified implies that the description was correct.

While there's probably some way to escape a leading digit in ${var} I'd opt to replace echo -e with printf, eg:
printf "\001\033[5m\033[7m\002%s\001\033[0m\002\n" "${var}"

NOTE: added \n on the end to insure we get the same effect as echo


One could also use printf '%b%s%b' '\001\033[5m\033[7m\002' "$var" '\001\033[0m\002\n' to be extra explicit.

You may use tput to avoid hardcoding sequences and make it more readable
blink=$(tput blink)
rev=$(tput rev)
sgr0=$(tput sgr0)
printf "\001%s%s\002%s%s\002\n" "$blink" "$rev" "$var" "$sgr0"

